# Separating UI/Business Logic - JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Alright first of all, take it easy as I'm a first time coder using JS and jQuery.

Now that that's out of the way: [Here is my code in JS/jQuery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntkjw.png)

Things I want to do:

1) Separate UI and Business logic (Looks like I've done it correctly but its not executing).

It may just be a syntax error...but how would people more seasoned handle this?

Keep in mind I'm a first time person using JS/jQuery.

Thank you for your input!

-An Aspiring coder

Comment: here is a link to my github where you can find the js file before I edited the code. https://github.com/NWShadowDev/PingPong

Comment: You should post the code here so that we can debug!

Comment: From looking at it, looks like you have not closed the brackets after `.submit` event and also the `return message` should be within the closing bracket of the `playPong`

Comment: First argument for `event-handler-callback-function` is `event-object`, why are you naming it as `playPong` ? You never passed argument as `event`, which `event(global ?)` you are referring in `handler-function`  ?

Answer (score -1):

I spoke too soon! I updated my gh-pages and master branch and it seems to work? It wasn't working on local but as soon as I made it remote it works just fine. So silly. Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: You should just delete this question then ;)